# JQuery .attr tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attr

I don't understand why .attr() will not change the background-color of div "outline" to red.

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="outline"></div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#outline {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
background-color: black;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY) CODE:

```
$("#outline").attr('background-color', 'blue');
```

Answer (score 2):

`background-color` isn't a html attribute, it's a style attribute - use `css` function instead.

```js
$("#outline").css('background-color', 'blue');
```

```css
#outline {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outline"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// To set the html style attribute, use .css()
// .css() is dedicated to set one or more
// styles at a time
$("#outline").css('background-color','blue');

// This is equivalent to the above
// .attr() is dedicated to set one or more html
// attributes at a time
$("#outline").attr('style', 'background-color:blue');
```

```css
#outline {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outline"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

background-color isn't an attribute, it's a css property.

Use :

```
$("#outline").css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
```